# Backup from multiple FTP folders to local and ZIP

Tags: backup, ftp

HI,

Is there any free / opensource tool that lets you to connect to FTP server and then download files and ZIP to archive them? I like to have codebase backups of multiple FTP sites to different ZIP files and save them for future if required.

App that can run on windows is preferred and should be able to schedule this.

THANKS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cobian](http://www.educ.umu.se/~cobian/cobianbackup.htm) can use FTP as a source or destination, support scheduling, multiple destinations for backups, compression, full/incremental/differential backups, and timestamped folders for daily backups, keeping multiple days worth of backups.

Answer (score 2):

wget? See http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Retrieval-Options

This will retrieve a directory tree that you can then zip using any of the usual command line zippers. You'd just put it all in a batch files and run it from the Task Scheduler.

JR]

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Super Flexible File Synchronizer](http://www.superflexible.com/). We do something similar using that tool. It isn't FOSS, but pretty cheap and has a lot of good features.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have though some simple scripting (batch file) would do the job. Either ftp or wget, and no doubt a bunch of others, can download the files. There are also a number of command line archiving programs. It can be run from the task scheduler.

I have similar requirement and have a script on the server do most of the work. By gathering and compressing them on the server there's less to download. A client side script, utilising wget, downloads the resulting archives, which already have filenames that include the date and time. So, it's a bash script run via cron on the Linux server and a batch file run via Task Scheduler on a Windows client.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have only FTP access to the server?

> If so, I suggest [NcFTP](http://www.ncftp.com/) and [7z](http://www.7-zip.org/) (7-zip).

If you can manage a logon to the server (like its yours and this is backup activity),

1. logon to the server through [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell),

   - [fire a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001179/unix-ssh-script-running-commands-on-remote-server) to archive and compress the directories of interest,
   - and, then just [SCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) them wherever.
     (but, please use [public authentication with ssh](http://www.ssh.com/support/documentation/online/ssh/adminguide/32/Public-Key%5FAuthentication-2.html) and scp)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement for my web server and thought about FTP but didn't like the unsecure connections...  So instead I created a backup script, added it to the Windows Task Scheduler service, and then configured it to run nightly.

The script performs a backup using [NTBackup](http://www.dscoduc.com/post/2009/01/16/File-Level-Backups-for-VistaWin2k8.aspx) for each folder I need backed up.  All backup files (.bkf) are saved into a single backup folder.

```
Call BackupInstance(folderPath, folderName)

Function BackupInstance(fstrFolderPath, fstrFolderName)
    Dim strJobName : strJobName = "Backup_" & fstrFolderName

    Dim strMonth : strMonth = GetMonth(Month(Date))
    Dim strDay : strDay = GetDay(Day(Date))
    Dim strYear : strYear = Year(Date)

    Dim strTimeStamp : strTimeStamp = strMonth & strDay & strYear & "-" & Replace(FormatDateTime(now,vbShortTime),":","")

    Dim strBackupFileName : strBackupFileName = fstrFolderName & "_" & strTimeStamp & ".bkf"
    Dim strBackupOptions : strBackupOptions = "/SNAP:off /M normal /L:f /V:yes /D " & chr(34) & "Backup of " & fstrFolderName & chr(34)
    Dim strSyntax : strSyntax = "presp1-ntbackup.exe backup " & _
                chr(34) & fstrFolderPath & chr(34) & _
                " /J " & strJobName & _
                " /F " & chr(34) & BackupFolder & "\" & strBackupFileName & chr(34) & _
                " " & strBackupOptions

    if blnDebug = True then wscript.echo "Backing up " & strBackupFileName
    objShell.run "cmd /c " & strSyntax, 0, True
end function
```

Each time the backup script runs it checks for x-number of days old backup files and then deletes them, keeping the backup folder from getting too full.

```
Call ArchiveFiles(BackupFolder)

Sub ArchiveFiles(strBackupFolder)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim objFolder : Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strBackupFolder)
    Dim colFiles : Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

    if blnDebug = True then wscript.echo "Found " & colfiles.count & " blkf file(s) in " & strBackupFolder

    Dim objFile
    For Each objFile in colFiles
        if lcase(Right(objFile.name,3)) <> "bkf" then
            if blnDebug = True then Wscript.Echo "Skipping " & objFile.name & " because it's not a backup file"
        elseif DateDiff("d", objFile.DateLastModified, Now) => intNumberOfDays then
            if blnDebug = True then Wscript.Echo "Removing " & objFile.Name & "  " & objFile.DateLastModified & " (" & DateDiff("d", objFile.DateLastModified, Now) & " days old)"
            objFso.DeleteFile(objFile.path)
        elseif DateDiff("d", objFile.DateLastModified, Now) < intNumberOfDays then
            if blnDebug = True then wscript.echo "Skipping " & objFile.Name & " because it's only " & DateDiff("d", objFile.DateLastModified, Now) & " days old)"
        else
            if blnDebug = True then wscript.echo "Unable to resolve last modified date for " & objFile.name
        end if
    Next
    err.clear
end sub
```

To offload the backup files I use [Windows Live Sync as a service](http://www.dscoduc.com/post/2009/05/19/Windows-Live-Sync-as-a-Service.aspx) to synchronize the Webserver backup folder my home computer.  This ensures that my backup files always exist on both the Webserver and my home computer.  From my home computer I use [Mozy online backup](http://mozy.com/) to backup both the web server files and my personal files.

Been using this for some time without any problems.  If you need more info or would like a copy of the script in it's entirety just let me know...